# WSL2 and PostgreSQL connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, wsl-2

Recently I've updated my Linux distro to wsl2. An error appeared, so my rails app couldn't connect to PostgreSQL. I followed the instructions from [this](https://skmcloughlin.github.io/configuring_postgresql_for_wsl2) article, and everything is working fine until I reboot my computer. After reboot, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` command displays a different IP address under the `nameserver` term. It appears that every time after I reboot/shutdown my computer, I'll have to change `pg_hba.conf`. Is there any way to configure wsl2 to have a stable `nameserver` so there'll be no need to change `pg_hba.conf` every time? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1533291/how-do-i-change-the-dns-settings-for-wsl2) post. This is what I have done to resolve the issue:

**1. Turn off generation of `/etc/resolv.conf`**

Using your Linux prompt, (I'm using Ubuntu), modify (or create) /etc/wsl.conf with the following content

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

**2. Restart the WSL2 Virtual Machine**

Exit all of your Linux prompts and run the following Powershell command

```
wsl --shutdown
```

**3. Create a custom `/etc/resolv.conf`**

Open a new Linux prompt and cd to `/etc`

If `resolv.conf` is soft linked to another file, remove the link with

```
rm resolv.conf
```

Create a new `resolv.conf` with the following content

```
nameserver 172.20.128.1
```

**4. Restart the WSL2 Virtual Machine**

**5. Edit `pg_hba.conf` in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg_version\data`**

```
TYPE    DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             172.20.0.1/16           md5
```

So, in this way, there is no need to edit `pg_hba.conf` every time after reboot.

Comment: **WARNING**: This will break a lot of things. Essentially, you will no longer be able to use the internet within the WSL after setting the nameserver to your local server